# Pandas groupby sum using two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, dataframe, sum

I have two very large Pandas DataFrames and would like to use them to guide each other in a fast sum operation.  The two frames look like this:

Frame1:

```
SampleName  Gene1   Gene2   Gene3
Sample1         1       2       3
Sample2         4       5       6
Sample3         7       8       9
```

(in reality, Frame1 is roughly 1,000 rows x ~300,000 columns)

Frame2:

```
FeatureName GeneID
Feature1    Gene1
Feature1    Gene3
Feature2    Gene1
Feature2    Gene2
Feature2    Gene3
```

(in reality, `Frame2` is about ~350,000 rows x 2 columns, with ~17,000 unique features)

I would like to sum the columns of Frame1 by Frame2's groups of genes.  For example, the output of the two above frames would be:

```
SampleName  Feature1    Feature2
Sample1            4           6
Sample2           10          15
Sample3           16          24
```

(in reality, the output would be ~1,000 rows x 17,000 columns)

Is there any way to do this with minimal memory usage?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to decrease the memory usage, I think your best option is to iterate over the first DataFrame since it has only 1k rows.

```
dfs = []
frame1 = frame1.set_index('SampleName')
for idx, row in frame1.iterrows():
    dfs.append(frame2.join(row, on='GeneID').groupby('FeatureName').sum())
pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).T
```

yields

```
FeatureName  Feature1  Feature2
Sample1             4         6
Sample2            10        15
Sample3            16        24
```

Comment: Brilliant approach!  I've only tested it with a smaller dataset but I'll try to get back soon with a full test case.  That being said, it looks like @jezrael may have the crown for smaller datasets at least.  I'll try to get back soon with a full test case, thank you!

Comment: Yes if it fits in memory, it is better to go with a vectorized solution rather than loops. `iterrows()` is way slower than applying it at once. You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can first create [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html), then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) columns by it and last [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
#create MultiIndex from df2
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(df2.FeatureName, df2.GeneID)),
       names=('FeatureName','GeneID'))
print (cols)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Feature1', 'Feature2'], ['Gene1', 'Gene2', 'Gene3']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
           names=['FeatureName', 'GeneID'])

#reindex columns by MultiIndex           
df = df1.set_index('SampleName').reindex(columns=cols, level=1)
print (df)
FeatureName Feature1       Feature2            
GeneID         Gene1 Gene3    Gene1 Gene2 Gene3
SampleName                                     
Sample1            1     3        1     2     3
Sample2            4     6        4     5     6
Sample3            7     9        7     8     9

#groupby by level 0 of columns and aggregate sum
print (df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum())
FeatureName  Feature1  Feature2
SampleName                     
Sample1             4         6
Sample2            10        15
Sample3            16        24
```

Comment: Works beautifully, thank you!  Also, the fastest code I could get to run so far. :)  The only caveat is that I have only tested it using a smaller dataset (375x3731 for Frame1 and 6040x2 for Frame2) - so I can't yet comment on its performance and memory usage with larger datasets.  Other than that, it was 79.935x faster than the above for loop approach.

Comment: I try it test with larger Dataframes with `%memit` without success. So I am currious about the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

#### One obnoxious line

```
Frame1.set_index('SampleName') \
    .rename_axis('GeneID', axis=1) \
    .stack().rename('Value') \
    .reset_index().merge(Frame2) \
    .groupby(['SampleName', 'FeatureName']) \
    .Value.sum().unstack()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong but when I try your code, the second line seems to fail. The error eventually comes back as 'TypeError: 'str' object is not callable'' - complete output available at: http://pastebin.com/raw/u4qmrUmi